# Slight difference of twilight and dusk

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, word-in-context

Can explain the difference between *twilight* and *dusk* please?

Comment: Have you looked in any online dictionaries for differences between the definitions?

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321150/dusk-vs-twilight).

Comment: I answered you in farsi, but it is deleted. So I repeat it in Enlglish. Twilight and dusk are synonyms. Both refer to a time that is nither dark nor light. But twilight is also used to reffer to the light just befor it gets dark. They are equvalent with شفق. The opposite can be dawn فلق.

Answer (score 2):

*[Twilight](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twilight?q=Twilight)*  (Oxford dictionary) is

> The soft glowing light from the sky when the sun is below the horizon, caused by the reflection of the sun’s rays from the atmosphere.

or

> The period of the evening when twilight is visible, between daylight and darkness.

*Dusk* is

> The darker stage of twilight
>   ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dusk))

So *twilight* is after the sun sets and before it gets dark. It refers to this entire time period, while *dusk* specifically and only refers to the last part of this time period, *eg* when it is starting to get really dark.

You can keep playing baseball, tennis, cricket, *etc* outside in the early twilight, but by *dusk* it would be really hard to see the ball without artificial lights.

It's important to note that *twilight* refers to the whole time period between sunset and darkness,  not just the early part. This is illustrated or reflected in the opening two lines from the "[Star-Spangled Banner](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/star-spangled-banner?q=Star-spangled+Banner)"  the National Anthem of the USA:

> Oh, say can you see by the dawn’s early light
>   What so proudly we hailed at the twilight’s last gleaming?

Note that the last part of twilight (its 'last gleaming')   is contrasted with the first part of dawn.

Answer (score 1):

Twilight is the period and the light quality when the sun is only a short way below the horizon. So

- morning twilight is the period before sunrise, and
- evening twilight is the period after sunset.

As for dusk, it is the opposite of dawn:

- dawn is the beginning of morning twilight, and
- dusk is the end of evening twilight.

What is a "short way"? Well that depends. There is

- civil twilight, where the sun is less than 6° below the horizon;
- nautical twilight: 12°;
- astronomical twilight: 18°.